# Design flow for "cashed in installments"

Tags: e-commerce, master-details

[image]

I have this situation on a web application:

- User search in box the pending instalments to cash in.
- Clicking on button "cash in" the instalments moves to box at the top

At this moment, the implementation has this problem:

- Box at the top get too large when the records is a huge number of instalments
- The two boxes are too similar for their shape. i try to assign different colors but is a poor solution.
- I think it's not intuitive to start working with the second box, but at the same time is important to allways have the situation of the registred records available.  the box of work should be at the top of page, next to the toolbar.

is there a better way to approach this situation? My only requirement is the 1024*800 resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You are combining two operations: "view cashed in installments" and "cash in installments." Separate these two functions into separate pages.

Replace the top "cashed in installments" box text with "pending cashed in installments" and move it to the bottom. Empty it after the user clicks apply (it will be empty when the user first starts cashing in installments).

> time is important to allways have the situation of the registred
>   records available.

Provide a completely separate page/interface for users to view "cashed in installments."